# Zombie kubernetes pod keeps being restarted by zombie Replica Set

Tags: kubernetes

I'm managing a kubernetes cluster and there is a duplicate pod that keeps coming back, but the duplicate ReplicaSet controlling it also keeps coming back after deletion. It's very strange. I also can't set the replica set to desire 0 pods, but that might be by design.

I can't really think of more information to share.

Anyone recognise this issue and know how to fix it?

Here's the ReplicaSet

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: cash-idemix-ca-6bc646cbcc
  namespace: boc-cash-portal
  uid: babc0236-2053-4088-b8e8-b8ae2ed9303c
  resourceVersion: '25466073'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2022-11-28T13:18:42Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: cash-idemix-ca
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cash-idemix-ca
    pod-template-hash: 6bc646cbcc
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas: '1'
    deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas: '2'
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '7'
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: cash-idemix-ca
      uid: 2a3300ed-f666-4a30-98b7-7ab2ebcb2a0d
      controller: true
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
  managedFields:
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-11-28T13:18:42Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-11-29T13:27:37Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      subresource: status
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/boc-cash-portal/replicasets/cash-idemix-ca-6bc646cbcc
status:
  replicas: 1
  fullyLabeledReplicas: 1
  observedGeneration: 1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cash-idemix-ca
      app.kubernetes.io/name: cash-idemix-ca
      pod-template-hash: 6bc646cbcc
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: cash-idemix-ca
        app.kubernetes.io/name: cash-idemix-ca
        pod-template-hash: 6bc646cbcc
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2022-07-19T11:45:27Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: fabric-ca-server-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: cash-idemix-ca-fabric-ca-server-home
      containers:
        - name: cash-idemix-ca
          image: ca.icr.io/samara-dev-container-images/cash-idemix-ca:0.3.0
          command:
            - sh
          args:
            - '-c'
            - >-
              sleep 1 && fabric-ca-server start -b
              $(IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME):$(IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD) --port 7054
              --idemix.curve gurvy.Bn254 --loglevel debug
          ports:
            - name: api
              containerPort: 7054
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME
              value: /idemix-config/fabric-ca-gurvy
            - name: IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cash-idemix-ca-admin-credentials
                  key: IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME
            - name: IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cash-idemix-ca-admin-credentials
                  key: IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: fabric-ca-server-home
              mountPath: /idemix-config/fabric-ca-gurvy
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: cash-idemix-ca
      serviceAccount: cash-idemix-ca
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: all-icr-io
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
```

Edit: The Fool was correct, there is a deployment that recreates the the ReplicaSet. Though in the settings it seems to say that it only want to create 1 replica; so I still don't see why it wants to create two of them.

I'm using Lens to manage my cluster, and it shows that the desired number of replicas is indeed 2. I can set it to 1, but the change won't persist. Anything else where I could look?
[image: lens]

*cash-idemix-ca Deployment:*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cash-idemix-ca
  namespace: boc-cash-portal
  uid: 2a3300ed-f666-4a30-98b7-7ab2ebcb2a0d
  resourceVersion: '25467341'
  generation: 10
  creationTimestamp: '2022-07-18T14:13:57Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: cash-idemix-ca
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cash-idemix-ca
    app.kubernetes.io/version: manual-0.2.1
    helm.sh/chart: cash-idemix-ca-0.12.0
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '7'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"cash-idemix-ca","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"cash-idemix-ca","app.kubernetes.io/version":"manual-0.2.1","helm.sh/chart":"cash-idemix-ca-0.12.0"},"name":"cash-idemix-ca","namespace":"boc-cash-portal"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"revisionHistoryLimit":0,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"cash-idemix-ca","app.kubernetes.io/name":"cash-idemix-ca"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"cash-idemix-ca","app.kubernetes.io/name":"cash-idemix-ca"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["-c","sleep
      1 \u0026\u0026 fabric-ca-server start -b
      $(IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME):$(IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD) --port 7054
      --idemix.curve gurvy.Bn254 --loglevel
      debug"],"command":["sh"],"env":[{"name":"FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME","value":"/idemix-config/fabric-ca-gurvy"},{"name":"IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME","name":"cash-idemix-ca-admin-credentials"}}},{"name":"IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD","name":"cash-idemix-ca-admin-credentials"}}}],"image":"ca.icr.io/samara-dev-container-images/cash-idemix-ca:0.3.0","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"cash-idemix-ca","ports":[{"containerPort":7054,"name":"api","protocol":"TCP"}],"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/idemix-config/fabric-ca-gurvy","name":"fabric-ca-server-home","readOnly":false}]}],"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"all-icr-io"}],"serviceAccountName":"cash-idemix-ca","volumes":[{"name":"fabric-ca-server-home","persistentVolumeClaim":{"claimName":"cash-idemix-ca-fabric-ca-server-home"}}]}}}}
status:
  observedGeneration: 10
  replicas: 2
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-11-28T13:53:56Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-11-28T13:53:56Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-11-29T13:37:38Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-11-29T13:37:38Z'
      reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
      message: ReplicaSet "cash-idemix-ca-6bc646cbcc" has timed out progressing.
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cash-idemix-ca
      app.kubernetes.io/name: cash-idemix-ca
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: cash-idemix-ca
        app.kubernetes.io/name: cash-idemix-ca
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2022-07-19T11:45:27Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: fabric-ca-server-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: cash-idemix-ca-fabric-ca-server-home
      containers:
        - name: cash-idemix-ca
          image: ca.icr.io/samara-dev-container-images/cash-idemix-ca:0.3.0
          command:
            - sh
          args:
            - '-c'
            - >-
              sleep 1 && fabric-ca-server start -b
              $(IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME):$(IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD) --port 7054
              --idemix.curve gurvy.Bn254 --loglevel debug
          ports:
            - name: api
              containerPort: 7054
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME
              value: /idemix-config/fabric-ca-gurvy
            - name: IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cash-idemix-ca-admin-credentials
                  key: IDEMIX_ADMIN_USERNAME
            - name: IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cash-idemix-ca-admin-credentials
                  key: IDEMIX_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: fabric-ca-server-home
              mountPath: /idemix-config/fabric-ca-gurvy
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: cash-idemix-ca
      serviceAccount: cash-idemix-ca
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: all-icr-io
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

Comment: It's almost certainly an operator manifesting the instructions of a CRD; and what kind of nonsense is "I can't think of more information to share?" when very clearly the name (or yaml) of the Pod and its ReplicaSet would enable someone to give you further guidance, to say nothing of what troubleshooting steps you've already tried and their outcomes. DO NOT put that in the comments, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74658224/edit) to expand on the specifics

Comment: replicaset usually is not created by itself.  You can also see it has a owner reference. So its the deployment controller that creates it again.